# Divide by Zero Exception raised despite edge case

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer-division, divide-by-zero

I am trying to handle a divide by zero exception manually in python3.5, however, it keeps ignoring my user defined case and giving the default exception. How can I avoid this? Any help is appreciated.

NOTE: I'm using a list as a stack, hence the last and is checking whether the top elem is 0. Also, the order is correct - I deliberately take the top elem as denominator

```
elif 'div' in command:
        if len(stack)!=0 and len(stack)!=1 and is_digit(stack[len(stack)-2]) and is_digit(stack[len(stack)-1]) and stack[len(stack)-1]!=0:
            op2 = stack.pop();
            op1 = stack.pop();
            stack.append(str( int(int(op1) / int(op2)) ) + '\n');
        else:
            stack.append(':error:\n');
```

This gives
    ZeroDivisionError: division by zero INSTEAD of :error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> "0" == 0
False
```

Your `if` statement tests for equality to `0`, but you don't convert to an int until you're doing the calculation, so your `!=` test is always going to pass as it's comparing a string against an integer.

(This is assuming your stack inputs are strings; if they aren't then you probably don't need the `int()` calls - but the fact that you're adding the result of the division to the stack as a string leads me to believe that they are.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Even though I tried doing the comparison with "0" initially, it didn't work. However, your answer led me to typecast stack[len(stack)-1] to int which worked perfectly

Comment: It's possible it was `"0\n"`, and thus `"0\n"`would not compare equal to `"0"`.